# Plotting a complex number on the Argand diagram

Tags: plotting, functions, complex

I want to plot `(0.25)^(2+i)` on the [Argand diagram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArgandDiagram.html).

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Just find the real and imaginary parts of your input. The x coordinates are the real parts and the y coordinates are the imaginary part. Then using `ListLinePlot` to make the plot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
expr = (0.25)^(2 + I)
x = Re[expr]; y = Im[expr]
ListLinePlot[{{x, y}}, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Real part", "Imaginary part"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2*Abs[x], 2*Abs[x]}, {-2*Abs[y], 2*Abs[y]}}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly to demonstrate some built-in functions for handling complex numbers:

```
a = 0.25^(2 + I);
{Abs[a], Arg[a]*180/π, Re[a], Im[a]}
```

> {0.0625, -79.4288, 0.0114661, -0.0614392}

```
ComplexListPlot[
 {0.25^(2 + I)}
 , PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black
    , Opacity[0.5]
    , AbsolutePointSize[6]
    ]
   }
 , AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}
 , PlotRange -> {{-.1, .1}, {-0.15, 0.05}}
 , Epilog -> {
   {Red, Dashed, Circle[{Re[a], Im[a]}, Abs[a]]}
   , {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]
    , Line[{{0, 0}, {Re[a], Im[a]}}]}
   }
 ]
```

[image]